# Share profile picture change to all users in my roster

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe, ejabberd, smack

I have a simple use case of sharing my profile picture to all contacts in my roster. I had implemented it using XMPP PEP which is a subset of Pub/Sub.

**PROBLEM**

When contacts in my roster come online, I receive the last published profile pic item of that contact. This happens every time the contact comes online. Am I missing a simple configuration.

I am using smack 4.1.0 android client. The XMPP server is ejabberd.

Comment: This is how PEP works: It send the last publish item, so that you can update it if your value is different.

Comment: @pikini, there two types of pubsub one persistent and another one is normal you are using persistent pubsub element.

Comment: is there any way to notify my rosters when update vCard info without PEP ?